# CIImage CVPixelBuffer is nil after scaling down

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ciimage, avvideocomposition

I'm using the `AVVideoComposition` API to get `CIImage`s from a local video, and after scaling down the `CIImage` I'm getting `nil` when trying to get the `CVPixelBuffer`.
Before scaling down the source frame, I'm getting the original frame `CVPixelBuffer`.
**Is there any reason the buffer is `nil` after scaling down?**

Sample:

```
   AVVideoComposition(asset: asset) { [weak self] request in
        let source = request.sourceImage
        let pixelBuffer = source.pixelBuffer // return value
        let scaledDown = source.transformed(by: .init(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
        let scaledPixelBuffer // return nil
   })
```

Comment: Can you try getting the pixel buffer using this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437853-render

Comment: Hey @Asteroid. Yes, I can! But it's less efficient, I'm trying to understand if I can just access it directly after scaling so I won't do another pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last line in your sample is incomplete. Did you mean `let scaledPixelBuffer = scaledDown.pixelBuffer`? If so, then yes, this won't work. The reason is that the `pixelBuffer` property is only available if the `CIImage` was created directly from a `CVPixelBuffer`. From the docs:

> If this image was create using the `init(cvPixelBuffer:)` initializer, this property’s value is the `CVPixelBuffer` object that provides the image’s underlying image data. […] Otherwise, this property’s value is `nil`.

The `CIImage` that is passed to the composition block was created from a pixel buffer provided by AVFoundation. But when you apply a filter or transform to it, you need to render the resulting image into a pixel buffer explicitly using a `CIContext`, otherwise you won't get a result.

If you want to change the size of the video frames the composition is using, you can use a `AVMutableVideoComposition` instead and set its `renderSize` to your desired size after it is initialized:

```
let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset) { … }
composition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
```

Comment: As always Frank, best in the business. Thanks, buddy!